# How do I add a 3D model to medeiapipe project?

Tags: java, filter, augmented-reality, mediapipe

So, I am trying to make an app with face-effects(Snapchat-like). I have tried augmented faces, but it has a huge video delay, so I am trying mediapipe now. and I have successfully tested their example app, the only problem is that they have basic models for filters. How do I add mine 3D models to mediapipe app?